# Xcode extensions disappears after system restart

Tags: file-extensions

I'm using the excellent SwiftFormat extension to format source code in Xcode. However every time I restart the machine the extension is not available in Xcode and when I look in System Preferences - Extensions, the Xcode Source Editor extensions options is not present.

To get the extensions back in System Preferences and working again in Xcode I have to drag Xcode out of the Applications folder, then drag it back. That seems to trigger the re-setting up of the extensions.

Anyone know why this is occurring and have a fix so I don't have to keep dragging Xcode around to fix this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but moving Xcode out of the application folder doesn't fix the problem 